# Creation of a class wrapper in Python

Tags: python, wrapper

I would like to do the following: given an instance of a `Base` class create an object of a `Wrapper` class that has all the methods and attributes of the `Base` class + some additional functionality.

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.base_param_1 = ...
         # some stuff

    def base_method_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # some stuff

class Wrapper(...):

    def  __init__(self, cls_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wrapper_param_1 = ...
        # some stuff

    def wrapper_method_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some stuff
```

The use case is like the following:

```
wrapper_obj = Wrapper(Base(*base_args, **base_kwargs), *wrapper_args, *wrapper_kwargs)
```

The expected behavior is that one can access `base_param_1, wrapper_param_1` and
`base_param_1`, `base_param_2`.

It is important that the fields of the `Base` class are the same in Wrapper (no copying).

I've seen that new functionality can be added in this way [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance), but this approach has caveats and is not recommended.

Inheritance seems not to be an option here, since I am an already constructed object and this `Wrapper` can take different classes, despite with common Base.

**EDIT**

It is also required that `Wrapper` object is identified as `Base` instance.

Comment: **class Wrapper(Base):**

Comment: @DarkKnight - Yeah, it has to inherited from Base. Thanks for pointing out. But it is not enough, since I have to get all of the parameters of the Base instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `__getattr__`. That way, `Wrapper` specific attributes are looked up first, then the wrapped object's attributes are tried.

```
class Wrapper:
    def  __init__(self, base_obj, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_obj = base_obj
        # some stuff

    def wrapper_method(self):
        return "new stuff"

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.base_obj, name)
        
w = Wrapper("abc")
w.wrapper_method()
# 'new stuff'
w.upper()
# 'ABC'
```

Comment: It is rather close to the desired. However, it is also desirable, that this Wrapper is identified as Base instance. Sorry for not specifying this in the question

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @schwobaseggl I came up to this solution. Probably, somehow mad, but with the desired functionality:

```
  class OuterWrapper:

    def __new__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):

      class InnerWrapper:

        def __init__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
          self.obj = obj

        def __getattr__(self, name):
          return getattr(self.obj, name)

      wrapper_obj = InnerWrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs)
      InnerWrapper = type('InnerWrapper', (obj.__class__, InnerWrapper, object), {})
      wrapper_obj.__class__ = InnerWrapper
      return wrapper_obj
```